# Javascript get serialize form variables in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form which I'm submitting through javascript `serialize()`.

Below form works fine but what i want if `<select name="comboForm">` seleted value is `0` then in JS script it should read that and if value of `<select name="comboForm">` is `=== 0` then it will `alert()` something else and if value is `>== 1` then `alert()` something else as below. Actually i do not know how to do this in the below script.

Please help. Thanks

```
success :  function(data){
   if (data[comboForm] === 0) {
   alert('Please select the item from list.');
   }else{
   alert('Item added successfuly to your cart.');
   }
}
```

**Form**

```
<form name="comboboxForm" method="post" id="item_form" action="singleitem.php">

<select name="comboForm">
   <option value="0">Select Something</option>
   <option value="1">ABC</option>
   <option value="2">DEF</option>
   <option value="3">GHI</option>
</select>

<div class="single-qty">
<input name="quantity" type="text" value="1" id="number" />
<div class="num-update">
<div class="increment" id="increment"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></div>
<div class="decrement" id="decrement"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></div>
</div>
</div>


<input type="submit" class="myFormSubmitD btn-style-2 mg-left-5" value="ADD TO CART">

</form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on('submit', '#item_form', function() {     
        var data = $(this).serialize();
        $.ajax({
        type : 'POST',
        url  : 'singleitem.php',
        data : data,
        success :  function(data){
            alert('Item added successfuly to your cart.');
        }
        });
        return false;
    });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just fetch the select element based in it's name and check the value:

```
if ($('[name="comboForm"]').val() == "0") { 
    alert('Something');
} else {
    alert('Something else'); 
}
```